# How to break the decision making stalemate with job offers

Tags: software-industry, job-offer

I've been recently inundated with job offers for being a developer and am struggling to decide between two positions and am wondering how I can break the stalemate in making the best decision. I have been presented with the following two offers:

**Position A**: One of the big four banks (6 month contract to hire)

```
       Salary:$105K/yr during contract. Converting to $80K + 10-15%   
       annual bonus after contract period; with a possible option to stay on 
       the contract at $105k/yr if conversion terms aren't favorable.

       Benefits: Benefits offered but paid for fully by employee.

       401K: 10% matching during contract. Matching % post contract 
       conversion unknown till conversion  discussion.

        Technology Ecosystem: .Net/SQL/Angular
```

**Position B:** US Government Contract (8 year ongoing guaranteed through 2019)

```
    Salary: $94K
    401K: 6% matching
    Conversion: No conversion, perpetual contract.
    Paid Time off: 3 weeks per year
    Holidays: All federal holidays paid
    Benefits: Health, Dental, Vision partially covered by employer. 
    Disability insurance and life insurance 100% covered by employer. 
    Bonus: Upto 5% per annum
    Technology Ecosystem:  EXTjs, MeteorJS, SQL, Angular, .Net
```

While the latter position clearly offers more, I find myself  struggling with how to best evaluate which is a better choice due in part to some of the grey areas of the first one and the option to continue on the original contract if the bank conversion terms aren't favorable. Any advice on how to make the best decision apart from strictly on face value terms would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Career advice like this is off topic, and unhelpful to anyone but the poster,  voting to close.

Comment: Do you want to be doing the same thing in the same place 2, 3,8 years from now or would you prefer the flexibility to pack your gear and leave after a year or two?

Comment: I am flagging to reopen as this is a huge challenges developers face. I believe it is not off-topic as it is an answerable question on how one would rationally approach this situation in terms of a developer generally addressing job offers. Bare minimum mark it as duplicate and point out other related (more general if need be) questions.

Answer (score 3):

1. Which job pays enough? Scratch the ones that don't.
2. Which job seems like it will be enjoyable. Scratch the ones that don't seem to be enjoyable.
3. If that leaves 0 jobs, redefine "enough" and "enjoyable" until you have at least 1 job.
4. Among the jobs that pass the filter, take the most enjoyable job as a baseline. Think hard if the additional money in other jobs is worth it.